# Joomla 3.9.19 get the constants from global configuration in component display function

Tags: component, custom-component, joomla-3.9, configuration, component-configuration

I have created a component and need to get a constant value in the component administrator and list the item according to it. I have tried different ways to get the constant value in the `display()` function in 'view.html.php'. I am expecting the value will be available in the default.php with `$this`.

I have defined the constant in the configuration.php file, a URL is supposed to be define.

```
define('CONSTANTVALUE', 'the URL string');
```

in the `display()` function,

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$constantvalue = $config->get('CONSTANTVALUE');
$this->constantvalue=  $constantvalue;
```

Seems this is not working. Then, I have tried:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->get('CONSTANTVALUE');
```

That is also not working.

I have referred to this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702981/joomla-3-how-to-get-value-from-configuration-file

How can I get the constant from configuration to component view file?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].

Comment: Please don't add random code to `configuration.php`.

Comment: @Adam-KER -  Please study how to add component config params to any component in Joomla here:  https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_configuration/en  And then anywhere in your component you can use the ComponentHelper->getParams() method to get your parameter (constant if you like). JoomlaStackexchange  is also full of answers on this topic already.

Comment: `getParams()` is a static method sorry, correctly again: `ComponentHelper::getParams()`, however in your own component you will get the component params via your Model as it is given in the document’ link above.

Comment: @Zollie Thank you so much for the response and for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to get it from global configuration set in configuration.php from anywhere within Joomla component, plugins, modules and templates you would use:

```
$config   = JFactory::getConfig();
$siteName = $config->get('sitename', 'No Site Name Specified');
```

OR

```
$siteName  = JFactory::getConfig()->get('sitename', 'No Site Name Specified');
```

You can also use name spacing in preparation for Joomla 4 with the following:

define

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
```

before the class opening.

```
$globalConfig = Factory::getConfig();
$siteName     = $globalConfig->get('sitename', 'No Site Name Specified');
```

Noting the 'sitename' might be case sensitive.